# Is it possible to convert a BAK type app to a APK type app on smartface?

Tags: apk, smartface.io

An app I created using Smartface is a .bak type file.Is it possible to convert a .bak app to an .apk app so it can be tested as most mobile app testing sites don't allow a .bak type file app to be tested.

I've tried converting it to .bar and then converting it to .apk however it wasn't successful.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Actually Smartface creates .apk or .zip files as output. The .bak file you mentioned should be the backup file of the project itself.

When you open and modify a project in Smartface IDE it automatically creates .bak file of the project file.